# left inverse is not equal to right inverse

Tags: functions, inverse

Is it possible to have a function which has both left and right inverse but they are unequal ?

A left inverse means the function should be one-to-one whereas a right inverse means the function should be onto.

How can both of these conditions be valid simultaneously without being equal ?

An example will be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right and left inverse](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428068/right-and-left-inverse), and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74363/looking-for-insightful-explanation-as-to-why-right-inverse-equals-left-inverse-f pretty much.

Comment: @rschwieb please notice that the questions you posted are about linear algebra and here is the general case

Comment: Dear @DominicMichaelis : The initial linked one has no relationship to linear algebra beyond the tag. I don't think your objection applies at all to the first one since the content is identical (and so is the answer.) What you say is true of the second one, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $f(g(x))=x$ and $h(f(x))=x$, then $h(x)=h(f(g(x))=g(x)$. So they have to be the same.

Answer (score 4):

For functions they are equal whenever they exist. Let $f$ be a function with left inverse $g$ and right inverse $h$, then 
$$g=g\cdot id=g(fh)=(gf)h=h$$

Comment: (+1) There is something about your answer that I like :-)

Comment: @robjohn Then you will also enjoy [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/428070/29335)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have mismatched left and right inverses.

If $f$ is a left inverse for $g$ and $h$ is a right inverse for $g$ (denote the identity function $\mathrm{id}(x)=x$) we have $f \circ g = \mathrm{id}$ and $g \circ h = \mathrm{id}$ so $f = f \circ \mathrm{id} = f \circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h = \mathrm{id} \circ h = h$. So $f=h$ is a double sided inverse.

This is true whenever you have an associative operation. Only non-associative operations allow one to have mismatched left and right inverses.

By the way...the equivalence of "existence of a right inverse" and "being onto" assumes the axiom of choice (for those who care about such things).